# The given key was not present in the dictionary when trying posting to facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need help from anyone that has ever done and solved the problem when trying to use this API, and got an error of "The Given Key Was Not Present..."

I got an error when trying post to facebook timeline., the accesstoken, and facebookid are already store in the database.

and here is the code :

```
public void SendComment(string p_strIdFB, string p_strMessage, string p_strWebLink, string p_strLinkAlias, 
        string p_strCaption, string p_strDescription, string p_strPictLink, string p_strIconLink, string p_strIdgods)
    {

        //FacebookSettings set = new FacebookSettings();
        //set.AppId = v_strApiKey;
        //set.AppSecret = v_strApiSecret;

        try
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict.Add("message", p_strMessage);
            if (ConverterManager.ConvertEmptyTextIntoString(p_strWebLink, "") != "")
            {
                dict.Add("link", p_strWebLink);
                if (ConverterManager.ConvertEmptyTextIntoString(p_strPictLink, "") != "")
                {
                    dict.Add("picture", p_strPictLink);
                }
                if (ConverterManager.ConvertEmptyTextIntoString(p_strLinkAlias, "") != "")
                {
                    dict.Add("name", p_strLinkAlias);
                }
                if (ConverterManager.ConvertEmptyTextIntoString(p_strCaption, "") != "")
                {
                    dict.Add("caption", p_strCaption);
                }
                if (ConverterManager.ConvertEmptyTextIntoString(p_strDescription, "") != "")
                {
                    dict.Add("description", p_strDescription);
                }
            }
            if (ConverterManager.ConvertEmptyTextIntoString(p_strIconLink, "") != "")
            {
                dict.Add("icon", p_strIconLink);
            }

            //FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(set);
            //app.Api("me/feed", dict, HttpMethod.Post);

            string idgods = "";
            idgods = p_strIdgods;
            BLGodsProfile objBLGodsProfile = new BLGodsProfile();
            tbmgodsprofile objGods = objBLGodsProfile.GetAccessToken(idgods);

            //FacebookWebClient fwc = new FacebookWebClient();
            var fwc = new FacebookClient(objGods.accesstoken);
            FacebookWebClient ff = new FacebookWebClient(objGods.accesstoken);

            ff.Post("/" + objGods.iduserfb + "/feed", dict);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This User : {0} Got Error Posting Facebook : {1}",p_strIdgods, ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

and here is the code for posting it to the facebook

```
private static void PostShoutToFb1(string p_strMessage, string idgods)
{
    BLFb objBLFb = new BLFb(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FbApiKey"],
                            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FbApiSecret"]);
    TdoFacebookUser objFbUser = objBLFb.GetFacebookUser();

    try
    {
        objBLFb.SendComment(objFbUser.Id, p_strMessage, "", "", "", "", "", "", idgods);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex, "GodsFeed");
    }
}
```

it's seem like the error is with the objBLFb.SendComment, cause when i'm trying to posting using mobile that i've developed, it's ok.

trims.

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: no, cause i try to post it from $.ajax(), so the response from the ajax is also 500-Internal Server Error. even the stackTrace when i look at the event log, it say The Given Key Was not present..

Comment: And what is the code of the Post method ? Can you edit your question and show where the dictionary (dict) is being used.

Comment: the 1st one is the dict that called to post, and the bottom one is the method to posted it to facebook wall.